# unable to see enhanced ecommerce data from localhost

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I currently have universal analytics setup and have implemented enhanced eCommerce on our site.

I've used Google Tag Assistant and the analytics debugger in Chrome and all my tags look fine and seem to send with no errors.

Is there any other reason why I wouldn't be seeing any transactions in the GA dashboard under eCommerce?

Here is what is sent when I do a purchase transaction:

```
ga('create','UA-xxxxxxx-xx' , 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase',{"Id":"33483","Name":"Bar","Brand":"Foo","Category":null,"Variant":null,"Price":27.00,"Quantity":18,"Coupon":"","Position":0});
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout',{"Step":4,"Option":""});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

EDIT:

I forgot to add I am testing this from localhost using cookiedomain : none

Comment: remember it takes 24 hour hours for data to show up in standard reports.   How long ago did you add it?

Comment: I've done a few transactions over the last several days.

Comment: We have now pushed this out to our dev environment. We are seeing pageviews and shopping cart statistics, but no transactions are working.